# Can this be done for images

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to achieve something like this [Tkinter Grid Dynamic Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704736/tkinter-grid-dynamic-layout)

unable to update the label with images to fit the root window

Comment: Are you asking if images can auto-resize? The answer is no.

Comment: No m asking if they could fit dynamically in the main window

Comment: Yes, you display images with labels, so anything you can do with a label  you can do with an image. Can you explain what you mean by "unable to update the label"? Why are you able? What have you tried, and how is what it does different from what you expect it to do?

Comment: So like, did you see the example from the main question? I want to do something like that but with labels which contains images. So i tried the same solution provide in above link but create_window and other Text parameters doesn't apply to Label in tkinter. I am trying to select the images from desktop to display in the window.

Comment: I can place them using place(x,y) and then keep updating x and y respectively but what I wanna know is can this be done using layout manager instead like the other post

Comment: Take the example you link to, and add a label to the `box`, and configure the label with an image. it's really not any more complicated than that.