# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting the following error while dragging the window to another screen:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!sortingframe.!dynamicgrid.!imagebuttonwidget"
```

I am trying to use [@bryan-oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) solution from [Tkinter Grid Dynamic Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47704736/tkinter-grid-dynamic-layout) to show buttons in a dynamic grid layout. When one button is pressed in the frame, I need to delete all the buttons inside the grid and clear the `tk.Text`. I tried adding a function for clearing the content:

```
    def clear_all(self):
        self.text.configure(state='normal')
        tags = self.text.tag_names()
        for tag in tags:
            self.text.tag_delete(tag)
        self.text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        self.text.configure(state='disabled')
```

I've read that this Exception occurs when attempting to access a widget that has already been destroyed.

To my understanding, the error message suggests that the error is caused by trying to access an `ImageButtonWidget`.
I am getting the error when dragging the window to another screen and after clearing the `tk.Text` so I am assuming that I get the error from the way I am deleting the buttons.

Besides the `tk.Text` widget, I don't have any other references to the buttons.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for your help.

---

Edit:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

class DynamicGrid(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        bg = 'gray80'
        self.text = tk.Text(self, wrap="char", borderwidth=0, 
                            background=bg, selectbackground=bg, selectforeground=bg, 
                            exportselection=0, insertofftime=0, relief="flat",
                            state="disabled", spacing2=8)
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nswe')
        
    def append(self, object):
        self.text.configure(state="normal")
        self.text.window_create("end", window=object)
        self.text.insert("end", ' ')
        self.text.configure(state="disabled")
    
    def clear_all(self):
        self.text.configure(state='normal')
        tags = self.text.tag_names()
        for tag in tags:
            self.text.tag_delete(tag)
        self.text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        self.text.configure(state='disabled')

class ImageButtonWidget(ctk.CTkButton):
    def __init__(self, parent, filename):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.configure(text=filename)


class SortingFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.images_frame = DynamicGrid(self)
        self.create_images()
        self.create_images()
        self.images_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nswe', columnspan=2)
        
    def create_images(self):
        # Create and display ImageButtonWidget instances for each image file
        self.images_frame.clear_all()
        for filename in range(2):
            image_widget = ImageButtonWidget(self.images_frame, str(filename)+'.png')
            self.images_frame.append(image_widget)
            

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Example")
        SortingFrame(self).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

A full traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 839, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "...\explorerEnv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\scaling\scaling_tracker.py", line 187, in check_dpi_scaling
    cls.update_scaling_callbacks_for_window(window)
  File "...\explorerEnv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\scaling\scaling_tracker.py", line 64, in update_scaling_callbacks_for_window
    set_scaling_callback(cls.window_dpi_scaling_dict[window] * cls.widget_scaling,
  File "...\explorerEnv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 136, in _set_scaling
    super()._set_scaling(*args, **kwargs)
  File "...\explorerEnv\lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\core_widget_classes\ctk_base_class.py", line 228, in _set_scaling      
    super().configure(width=self._apply_widget_scaling(self._desired_width),
  File "...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1675, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "...AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1665, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!sortingframe.!dynamicgrid.!imagebuttonwidget"
```

Comment: It would  be best if you provided a single block of code that we can run to reproduce this problem. You don't show any code that uses the `ImageButtonWidget` or `DynamicGrid` classes. Also, please show the full traceback.

Comment: @BryanOakley I added a single block of code

Comment: This doesn’t look like a minimal example. Are you sure all of that code is required to reproduce the problem? For example, is pandas required? See [mcve]

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry, I've changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem** was that the `tk.Text` object didn't destroy the `customtkinter widgets` as expected. Although the function removed them from the screen, when trying to move the app to another window it tried to access those deleted button for some reason.

**The solution** was to add a list that stores the `tk.Text` content and to destroy each widget manually.

---

I appended this line in the **`__init__`** function:

```py
self.content = []
```

This line in the **`append`** function:

```py
self.content.append(object)
```

The new **`clear_all`** function:

```py
    def clear_all(self):
        self.text.configure(state='normal')
        tags = self.text.tag_names()
        for tag in tags:
            self.text.tag_delete(tag)

        self.text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        for object in self.content:
            object.destroy()
        self.content.clear()
        self.text.configure(state='disabled')
```

---

- Important to mention that I was only having this problem with the `ctk.CTkButton`. When I replaced the `ctk.CTkButton` with `tk.Button` the first implementation of the class worked.